# Ubuntu 10.04,10.10,11.10 boot but don't load after fresh install, graphics to blame?

Tags: 11.10, 10.10, 10.04, 64-bit, boot-failure

I've been running ubuntu fine few months ago then decided to reinstall everything and get a fresh start. After about few months of windows I couldn't stand it and re-installed ubuntu.
It was all running nice and smooth installation and got up to the restarting point:

1. Restarted after fresh install of ubuntu on top of windows 7 Ultimate
2. 64-bit Everything was running fine Grub and all I selected ubuntu started loading and it stops at 2 different points
3. When running 2 screens it has "_" in top left corner flashing or just a blank screen
4. Displays "[OK]" and in next line  "_" flashes.
5. Test with one screen FRESH install some random flashes of loadscreen or background repeatedly ( looks as though GPU drivers or something were going really bad).

My RIG:
ASUS M4a89gtd pro/usb3 
VTX 3d 6970
8GB Kingston ddr3 ram
AMD Phenom 2 x6 1100t
(anything else needed please leave a note)

Comment: boot into windows - look at your system information.  What graphics card do you have?  Can you boot with a Ubuntu live CD to a GUI desktop?

Comment: Do you have multiple harddrives?

any previous grubs or any thing?

Comment: CD's worked fine after install it all crashed. *FIXED* Now.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to fix it. Ubuntu 11.10 64BIT

I first of all **Put in LiveCD and UNPLUGGED LAN cable** (perhaps some updates were messing it up I'm not sure) then proceeded with the installation and have **disabled Automatic Logging In** finished installation and turned ubuntu on worked fine but B**EFORE logging in I disabled 3D Unity**. Then just about managed to get it all fixed by replacing drivers using this askubuntu thread to install drivers & set up multi-screen: [ATI Radeon HD with Catalyst driver stuck mirroring screens](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69929/ati-radeon-hd-with-catalyst-driver-stuck-mirroring-screens)